# How can I render HTML tags in a variable in a twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a variable in my twig template called *description*.
The variable is a string with an html em tag in it. When I go to the webpage to view the field, the html em tags are stripped out of the string.
I am on a **Drupal 8** site and my variable was rendered through
`\Drupal::service('renderer')->render()` The twig `autoescape` parameter is set to false.

Using the twig debugger, I can see that my markup object includes the html em tags so I know that the problem is how twig is processing the string.
I've read in other posts to use the `|raw` tag but this has no effect.
What can I do to make the HTML in my twig variable render properly?

**Update:** I've included a screenshot of my output from `{{ dump(description) }}`
[image]

Comment: can you share the line you have used into your twig file to print that variable?

Comment: {% if description is not empty %}
    <p>{{ description }}</p>
{% endif %}

Comment: try to allow uses of <em> tag `{{ description|striptags('<em>')|raw }}`

Comment: Just tried this but no difference. I know that my variable has the html em tags because I can see them when I run dump( description ).

Comment: can you share a screen of your dump results? try to update the post by adding your screenshot.

Comment: I've included the screenshot with the original question.

Comment: try `{{ description.string | raw }}` to access string property of description object

Comment: This causes the description variable to show no output.

Comment: so don't use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->render()` try to pass your variable directly to your template and print it directly as mentioned into Clive answer.

Answer (score 3):

> my variable was rendered through
>   \Drupal::service('renderer')->render()

Don't do that - Drupal sets Twig up to understand render arrays. Just use:

```
{{ original_description_render_array }}
```